# jackson serialization - avoid scientific notation for numbers

Tags: json, jackson, json-serialization

When I jackson object mapper to serialize a class, the resulting json consists of numbers in scientific notation. Below are some example -

```
0.0001 -> 1.0E-4
123456789 -> 1.23456789E8
0 -> 0.0
```

Is there a way to avoid this so the numbers are written as is? I tried to use JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS (shows deprecated now) and JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN, but did not help.
Thanks.